# Unity3d issue with connecting

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm coming here today because I've encountered an issue I can't seem to be able to solve on my own. I've been working for my company on Unity for 2 months now, and since 2-3 weeks I am no longer able to connect to my account via Unity.

Here's what happens when I try to do so :

- I launch Unity, works fine.
- I try to sign in : I can write down my mail, my password, it even tells me if I'm typing the wrong password, but as soon as the password is the good one, it crashes with this error window :

[image: Error screen screenshot]

I sent a mail to the support, and even though they were quite quick to answer, it didn't help me much, they advised to uninstall and delete every single files from Unity, as well as try to disable firewall and antivirus, and to check if the problem persisted when I changed my internet connection. None of those worked. I also tried connection with another account, doesn't seem to work either. Finally, I can connect without a single issue to Unity's website with my ID/password.

Comment: Do you have colleagues? If so can they connect with their pcs? Does your acc logs in on another computer ? Did you try signin with your work pc, at another place like your home?

Comment: They can connect to Unity with their pcs without any issue, I tried signing in with my work pc at home, didnt work. I tried to connect on another PC, it worked

Comment: Just wildly guessing, could you been usign somekind of vpn that has changed your connection properties before ?

Comment: No I didn't, but i created and ran a virtual machine to run a local server with symfony. I already had virtualbox installed since a long time though.

Comment: Just in case some people were mistaken, yes it worked on another computer, but it was for sole purpose of testing, i have to get it to work on my own computer.